# Return multiple instances from query firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

Currently building an App in Xamarin forms (c#). The app has a firebase backend. The user can submit journal logs within the app that are stored on firebase.

The current feature I'm working on will retrieve all the log instances from the server, based on the users ID (uID), before displaying them to the screen. The current solution I have only returns the most recent log instance:

```
public async void getLastLogInstance(Guid uID)
    {

        //fetch last log user had information provided by user
        var getUser = (await firebaseClient
            .Child("UserLogs")
            .OnceAsync<UserLogs>()).Where(a => a.Object.UserID == uID).LastOrDefault();


        //if getUser equals null then the user has no log history
        if (getUser == null)
        {
            logDate.Text = "No recent logs found";

        }
        //valid logs found, return data, successful login
        else
        {
            var Content = getUser.Object as UserLogs;
            logDate.Text = Content.logTime;
            logData.Text = Content.logData;
            happinessRating.Text = Content.sliderValue;


        }


    }
```

I need to have access to the individual properties that have been returned e.g. Content.logTime, Content.logData

I have found a way of returning multiple instances, however I can't access the individual properties mentioned above. The below code is taken from another module that has a different purpose, however the purpose of this module is similar to the one above

```
 public async void DisplayContent(Guid idAsGuid)
    {
        try
        {
            /*getInstance will hold a list 
         * of result instances with the matching userID
         * */
            getResults = (await firebaseClient
            .Child("phq9Results")
            .OnceAsync<phq9Results>()).Where(a => a.Object.UserID == idAsGuid).Select(item => new phq9Results
            {
                UserID = item.Object.UserID,
                overallResult = item.Object.overallResult,
                submissionDate = item.Object.submissionDate

            }).ToList();

            //order list so most recently added result is positioned first
            var orderedResults = getResults.OrderByDescending(x => x.submissionDate).ToList();

            listOfResults.ItemsSource = orderedResults;

            

        }
        catch
        {
            return;
        }
```

Many thanks for your help in advance!!

Comment: What are the elements in orderedResults?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT UserID, overallResult, submissionDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a fairly simple solution

Read in all instances of the data you are trying to read by doing this

```
            //fetch all logs connected to the users ID (uID)
        var getUser = (await firebaseClient
            .Child("UserLogs")
            .OnceAsync<UserLogs>()).Where(a => a.Object.UserID == uID).Select(item => new UserLogs
        {
            sliderValue = item.Object.sliderValue,

        }).ToList();
```

Then loop through the getUser list, accessing the properties through item.x

```
            //loop for each item in object
        foreach (var item in getUser)
        {

           total = total + item.sliderValue

        }
```

Comment: You can mark this answer later which will help more people with same problem:).